# I can't drag the image, jQuery code is not working for some reason

Tags: jquery

The first module of code is based on Bootstrap which contains id="draggable" for each image.

Second module is simple jQuery in order to drag the images. However, it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="divClass">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="./images/h.jpg" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter" id="draggable">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="./images/t.jpg" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter" id="draggable">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="./images/p.jpg" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter" id="draggable">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="./images/o.jpg" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter" id="draggable">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="./images/n.jpg" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter" id="draggable">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="./images/y.jpg" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter" id="draggable">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You missed $( and jQuery UI. It would help if you added images from placeholder.com

Comment: IDs need to be unique

Comment: You only have one set of codes

Comment: @mplungjan I added the Jquery UI link, but I want all of those images to be draggable, do I still have to declare all ids unique. I uploaded the full code you can check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs need to be unique

Add the class to the div or the image

```js
$(function() {
  $(".img-fluid").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="divClass">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=H" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=T" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=P" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=O" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=N" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Y" alt="" class="img-reponsive img-fluid" data-value="letter">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you kindly do with the images as well, I tried but it's not working! I would be thankful!

Comment: The images are draggable if their container is. I added letters because I did not have images

Comment: I now added images and change to .img-fluid which are now draggable